# WxPython GLCavans not working on some machine

Tags: python, wxpython, glcanvas, wxglcanvas

I'm trying to run this simple (and useless) script on different machines:

```
import wx
from wx import glcanvas

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
glcanvas.GLCanvas(frame)
```

It seems to work (it ends gracefully without errors) on most PCs, but i'm encoutering problem with lenovo machines, in fact, if I launch the very same script on these machines (in particular the T470p) it fails with `segfault` on all of them (we have a bunch of them in the office).

I tried to use `pyinstaller`, I thought thought of a problem in the default libraries, but even when i use the libraries that are working on my machine the `segfault` is still there. Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this bug?

EDIT

As asked: The Lenovo machines have 32Gb of RAM, and they are generally more powerfull than the others we have in the office, as I already explained the error is:

```
[1]    18686 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the `segfault` appears for both the script and the exe compiled version

Comment: What error does it return? It could have to do with `recursion depth`, at least that was the problem for me in a similar situation. Maybe the lenovo machines have less RAM? A bit more information would certainly help to understand the situation. Are you running the code or the exe file btw?

Comment: I just updated the Question, the example it is even smaller now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Bug with Wayland (still not fully supported I guess), you just need to switch back to Xorg:

[Bug Ticket on Official Repository](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/915#issuecomment-403842325)